# type definition for constructor functions and properties of a constructor function

Tags: typescript

Lets say we have a library that creates a constructor function for us. 
We can pass a Object as the first parameter and this properties will added to the constructor function directly.

this example can look like:

```
let Tiger = can.Construct.extend({
    leg: 3
});
```

We have now 2 possibilities:

1. create an instance `let bar = new Tiger('foo', 'bar')`
2. modify the constructors properties `Tiger.leg = 4`

**second will throw an error with my current type definitios**

> Property 'leg' does not exit on type ConstructFactory

my current type definition looks like:

```
declare namespace can {

    interface ConstructFactory {
        new(...args: any[]): Construct;
    }

    class ConstructStatic {
        static extend(staticProperties: Object): ConstructFactory;
    }

    class Construct extends ConstructStatic {
        constructor(...args: any[]);
    }
}
```

if i return a type `any` instead of `ConstructFactory` the `Tiger.leg` will not throw an error, but now i can't create an instance because the constructor definition is lost.

- typescript playgroud [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20namespace%20can%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20ConstructFactory%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20new(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20Construct%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20ConstructStatic%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20static%20extend(staticProperties%3A%20Object)%3A%20ConstructFactory%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Construct%20extends%20ConstructStatic%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20Tiger%20%3D%20can.Construct.extend(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20leg%3A%203%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0ATiger.leg%20%3D%204%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20bar%20%3D%20new%20Tiger('foo'%2C%20'bar'))
- [jsbin example for the constructor function class](http://jsbin.com/govuqi/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you're looking for:

```
declare namespace can {

    interface ConstructFactory {
        new(...args: any[]): Construct;
    }

    class ConstructStatic {
        static extend<T>(staticProperties: T): ConstructFactory & T;
    }

    class Construct extends ConstructStatic {
        constructor(...args: any[]);
    }
}


let Tiger = can.Construct.extend({
    leg: 3
});

Tiger.leg = 4

let bar = new Tiger('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: This give you type support on bar:

`interface ConstructFactory<T> {
        new(...args: any[]): Construct & T;
}`